# How to send HTTPS request from login box in C#

Tags: c#

I am using c#, Microsoft AjaxToolKit.

I am using `ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender` for the login page, now what I am trying that in my login page it should sent the **HTTPS Request** POST for the authentication of logging user. Below is the snapshot of my code on the click of login button.

```
 protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add your DB Authentication Module here....
        //This is just for testing
        if (loginId.Text.Equals("user") && pwd.Text.Equals("user"))
            successLabel.Text = "Welcome User";
        else
            successLabel.Text = "Authentication Failed...Retry";
        successLabel.Visible = true;
        Loginlnk.Visible = false;
        Signuplnk.Visible = true;
    }
```

The above code is just for testing purpose, please suggest how can I proceed to have POST HTTPS WEB REQUEST to authenticate the valid user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string username = "user";
string password = "pass";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yoursite.com");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)";

request.Method = "POST";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
{
    writer.Write("nick=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LAS_VEGAS, I will be sending my username and password as POST data, so where do I need to send the request for further processing, I mean we must call some fucntion or procedures in which our username and password will be passed to get validated, please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me:

```
    var request = WebRequest.Create(_url);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
```